# Interaction between View Controller in Container View and Parent Controller in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicontainerview

I only recently started programming for iOS (in Objective C). I am pretty new to most concepts of iOS programming. I've been able to get by with Tutorials and stackoverflow threads, but now I've run into a wall. I am using the Storyboard to build my interface, so right now I have this set-up:

I have a standard "View Controller" which contains a "Container View" and two buttons. The Container View embeds a "Page View Controller".

How do I now use the buttons in the Parent "View Controller" to execute methods in the "Page View Controller"? I have heard of Delegation or working with Selectors, but I really don't understand how either of those would work in code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a property for page view controller in your View controller's interface declaration.

`@property (nonatomic, assign) UIPageViewController *pageVC;`

2. Give an 'id' to the segue which embeds the page vc within the container, say **segueIdentifier**.
3. Implement `prepareForSegue` method in view controller and access the segue's destination view controller to assign it to the local property

```
    -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"]) {
            if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UIPageViewController class]]) {
                self.pageVC = (UIPageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            }
        }
    }
```

Once the segue is executed, you can directly access the embedded page view controller form the main view controller.

Comment: For some reason, the code block refuses to take the correct `code` formatting in my answer.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but this answer was correct, I forgot marking it as such and just found it again going back through my SO profile. Sorry about that!